# Read two whole numbers and find all the positive multiples of the first that are less than the second

Tags: c, function, for-loop, structure

The problem goes like this:"Read two int numbers a and b. a is between 1 and 10 ,and b is between 20 and 50.The program must print the values generated and also must print the multiples that exist between 1 and b.

The program i wrote goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int num = 0;
    printf("\nIntroduce the first number:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nIntroduce the second number:");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    for(a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        for(b = 20; b <= 50; b++)
        {
            while(a < b)
            num = a * a;
        }
        printf("\n%d",num);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

That's the program i wrote but i have wrong. I have to use the for funcion obligatorily, but i have no idea to how make the program work.

All help appreciated!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. A multiple of any  number is infinite. For example, a multiple of 2 is infinite. What is the question?

Comment: what is the desired output? can you give an example if for instance the program should work, what should it print out with 9 and 25

Comment: Oh ok . To give an example: a=4 and b=37 then the answer should be the  multiples of 4 until 37,  which would go like this:4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36. So the final output should be that sequence.        Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: You have a logic issue not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, that would print out your desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
  int a,b;
  int i;
  int num=0;

  printf("\nIntroduce the first number:");
  scanf("%d",&a);

  printf("\nIntroduce the second number:");
  scanf("%d",&b);

  for(i = 1; ;i++) {
    num = a * i;
    if(num > b)
        break;
    printf("%d ", num);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I did not include the error handling stuff like if user inputted a value beyond the specified range of input you should ask for it again. I suggest that if you want your program to be more robust you should include that.

If you have any further questions just ask :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i needed. And also ik sorry if i didnt expressed the question nor myself right.

Answer (score -1):

put the printf inside the second loop after num =a*a

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b;
int num=0;
printf("\nIntroduce the first number:");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("\nIntroduce the second number:");
scanf("%d",&b);
  for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
   {
   for(b=20;b<=50;b++)
   {
       while(a<b)
        num=a*a;
        printf("\n%d",num);
 }

 }
getch();
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What kind of logic is it ? why a is looping from a =1 always. Why the square of a number? The question is to find the multiples between the range for a given number.

Comment: my mistake use num =a*b